# In Islamic tradition, what actions or reasons will put you to spend eternity on Hell?

Tags: belief, jannah, hell, atheism

I'm a Catholic and I'm stuck with an atheist in [a discussion](https://plus.google.com/b/103989487441001641495/103989487441001641495/posts/bqXF4TKgtLm) regarding, according to the atheist folk, illogical result receiving the consequences of choosing not to believe in something, as in: *I can't fly out of my car if I don't fasten my seatbelt, because I don't believe I'll get in a crash.*

Basically, he thinks that I would spent eternity on *Islamic* Hell because I don't believe in its existence  or I don't believe in the *Islamic* God. In Catholicisms, we have very good defined teachings on these regards, about what is Hell and how you get there (to put in some way), But for the sake of our conversation, **I would like to know what actions or reasons will put you to spent eternity on Hell, according to the Islamic Tradition?**

I have tried to explain to him that Muslims profess to hold the faith of Abraham, and together with us [The Catholic Church] they adore the one, merciful God, mankind's judge on the last day. But he keeps using the distinctive.

Pax et bonum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that Allah has said he will not forgive is Shirk which is associating partner with Allah or comparing Allah to something else.

"Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin." - [4:48]

There are many major sins but if you repent Allah will for give you. Allah has 99 names including Ar-Rahim (The All-Merciful), Al-Ghaffar (The Forgiving), At-Tawwib (The Guide to Repentance) and Al-Afu (The Forgive).

If your question is will Christians go to hell then only Allah knows the answer to that. Yes we do believe that if we disbelieve then we will end up in hell but some people know the truth (they know that there is only one worthy of worship and his name is Allah) but they decide not to believe maybe because they are ignorant or some other reason. However there are people who are trying to find out the truth but they still dont understand and they may be confused. As this is not their fault and Allah knows what is in their heart they may be saved from hell fire. This could apply to mentally unstable people etc.

Comment: Killing an innocent believer also gets you to hell permanently....
“And whoever kills a believer intentionally, his recompense is Hell to abide therein, and the Wrath and the Curse of Allah are upon him, and a great punishment is prepared for him” [an-Nisa’ 4:93].

Answer (score 1):

**Disbelief in God** and **associating partner with Him** - these two reasons guarantee an **eternal** place in hell.

- *And for those who disbelieved in their Lord is the punishment of Hell, and wretched is the destination.* [[67:6](http://quran.com/67/6)]
- *Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.* [[4:48](http://quran.com/4/48)]

<sub>for other sins than these two, [they will be punished in hell for a period of time, then they will be given paradise.](http://sunnah.com/urn/679020)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Brother Jorge, I myself am a Christian and still searching for the Truth and the answers to my questions. That s why I m here, but first you also have to investigate if the manners we practice our belief in God is according God s will. I don t want to attack your faith, but people have to stand still at certain moment and try to look at their religion from a different angle. Do we (Protestants, Catholics) put our trust/faith only in God or also in e.g saints and Mother Mary? Does this way of believe guarantee us that we don t go to Hell just like an atheist/unbeliever? We must ONLY have faith in God/Allah! Even if the church will ex communicate a person because of his disagreement with the way an christian/catholic should serve God, then it s better to be ex communicated and go to Heaven than to hell. Be openminded and search also for the Truth!